# Не работает кнопка завершения процесса, почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu, psutil

Нужна помощь, решил написать мини диспетчер задач, но вот проблема не работает кнопка **`"Kill"`** - чтобы завершить процесс нажимаю ее, но ничего не происходит.

Вот весь код:

```py
import psutil
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Menu, simpledialog


class TaskManagerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Task Manager")

        self.process_tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root)
        self.process_tree["columns"] = ("PID")
        self.process_tree.column("#0", width=250)
        self.process_tree.column("PID", width=100)
        self.process_tree.heading("#0", text="Process Name")
        self.process_tree.heading("PID", text="PID")
        self.process_tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, width=40)
        self.search_entry.pack()

        self.process_tree.bind("<Button-3>", self.show_context_menu)

        update_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Update", command=self.update_running_processes)
        update_button.pack(pady=10)
        
        add_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Add Process", command=self.add_process)
        add_button.pack()

        self.selected_pid = None
        self.process_groups = {}  # Словарь для группировки процессов по имени

    def clear_process_groups(self):
        for process_group in self.process_groups.values():
            self.process_tree.delete(process_group)
        self.process_groups = {}

    def update_running_processes(self):
        self.clear_process_groups()  # Очистка групп перед обновлением
        search_text = self.search_entry.get().lower()

        for pid, name in self.get_running_processes():
            if search_text in name.lower():
                process_group = self.process_groups.get(name, None)
                if process_group is None:
                    process_group = self.process_tree.insert("", "end", text=name, values=(pid))
                    self.process_groups[name] = process_group
                else:
                    self.process_tree.insert(process_group, "end", text=name, values=(pid))
                    
    def update_all(self):
        self.update_running_processes()

    def get_running_processes(self):
        processes = []
        for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
            processes.append((process.info['pid'], process.info['name']))
        return processes

    def select_process(self, event):
        item = self.process_tree.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
        if item:
            self.selected_pid = int(self.process_tree.item(item, "values")[0])
        else:
            self.selected_pid = None

    def show_context_menu(self, event):
        menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Kill", command=self.kill_selected_process)
        menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def add_process(self):
        process_name = simpledialog.askstring("Add Process", "Enter process name:")
        if process_name:
            try:
                process = psutil.Popen(process_name)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            self.update_all()  
    
    def kill_selected_process(self):
        if self.selected_pid is not None:
            try:
                process = psutil.Process(self.selected_pid)
                process.terminate()
                process.wait()
                process.suspend()

            except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                pass
            self.update_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = TaskManagerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...

    def show_context_menu(self, event):
        print(f'event): {event}') # 
        
        self.select_process(event)                                  # !!! +++ <----
        
        menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Kill", command=self.kill_selected_process)
        menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]